# Retornar pessoa e lista de telefones

Tags: java, jsf, hibernate, hql

Tenho uma entidade chamada `Pessoa`. Essa entidade tem uma lista de telefones da entidade `Telefone`.

Como faço pra trazer as informações da pessoa e popular a lista de telefones dessa pessoa em um `select` só com `hql`?

---

Ao utilizar a query `select u FROM Pessoa`, são retornados muitos dados. Gostaria de otimizar e trazer somente os campos `código`, `nome` e a lista de telefones.

O resultado esperado seria igual a esse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado pela atenção

Comment: Já tentou fazer um Join?, depois é só pegar os registros no select, ex: `select u, t.telefone`

Comment: Poste o código das entidades `Pessoa` e `Telefone`, por favor

Answer (score 0):

Você mapeou o relacionamento das entidades Pessoa e Telefone?

Se estiverem mapeados com `eager` o Hibernate fará isso para você. Através de hql você precisará usar o join.

Algo como:

```
Select u FROM Pessoa u join Telefone t where u.idPessoa = t.idPessoa
```